# "Add New Set" button in "Manage Attribute Sets" is not visible...

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

Hope someone can help with this... For some reason the "Add New Set" buton is not visible in the "Manage Attribute Sets".

I have tried everything... gone through all settings... nothing seems to be wrong... Desperate as I was, I even made a complete reinstall on a clean site (and DB)... Same issue...

The "default" set is empty, and there are no unassigned attributes in the list... I think it's weird... (see attached images)

Anyone have an idea of what(if) I'm doing(something) wrong? Everything else seem to be working ok!

(thanks in advance)

Mike
[image]
[image]

Comment: I hope there is a conflict with javscript. Please check the firebug's console. It will give you some idea to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I hope there are issue `with  missing adminhtml layout files`.So
copy the `adminhtml layout file` to another system and replace yourfile
Just copy `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\`  folder and files from another system to
to `\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\`

Comment: Dear Amit, Thanks again.... I tried replace the'template'-folder as you suggested... but it did not make any difference... then I tried replacing the whole 'adminhtml'-folder... same problem... :(

Comment: My new added attribute not visible at Unassigned Attributes, may i know the possibilities of issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because there is template files missing in magento 1.9.2.3 version adminhtml catalog directory.
You will need to add the files from magento old version manually to make the attribute section work properly. you can find more detail here:
[magento attribute set missing button](http://www.crazywebdevelopers.com/add-attribute-set-button-not-showing-in-magento/)